# How to/Is it possible to create a listener corresponding with touchstart event in Firefox Windows touch desktop?

Tags: javascript, windows, firefox, events, touch

I have to trigger some methods specifically on the start of touch event in Firefox Windows touch screen (desktop). I have noticed that due to [this bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=736048) (please vote up) touch events are disabled by default in Firefox (desktop).
However, not even "mousedown" is triggered when you physically put your finger on the screen and hold it.

I know that you can enable touch events in

> config:about

but I can't consider that as a solution as you cannot switch that on programmatically.

The sequence of events should be as follows (that's what it is in e.g. Chrome):

> touchstart > [touchmove]+ > touchend > delay > mousemove > mousedown > mouseup > click

[see this doc for more details](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2013/04/detecting-touch-its-the-why-not-the-how/)

However, due to the bug mentioned above and the fact that we are dealing with touch devices the actual sequence is the following:

> mousemove > mousedown > mouseup > click

[Testbed](http://jsfiddle.net/DamianS1987/sng8rq3j/) - to show all of the events triggered

So as a result there is NO event triggered on the start of the screen touch?

My question, and a solution to the issue I face is - is it possible to listen to any events in Firefox (desktop) that are triggered as is "touchstart" in e.g. Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

I've asked the question in bugzilla and got some help. See [this issue](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1194963).

It appears that updating Firefox to 42.0a2 (aurora update channel Firefox Developer Edition) solves the issue. Both pointer events and touch events work great.

So far I haven't found a solution for earlier versions of Firefox.